# JavaFX custom controls with @NamedArgs: Cannot bind to untyped object

Tags: javafx-8, fxml, fxmlloader

I want to create an application with FXML with two custom controls, where one of them needs a reference to the other.

The first class gets the reference to the second class via a constructor argument. This is also available in the FXML with the `@NamedArgs` annotation.

```
public SelectWeekControl(@NamedArg("dayControl") SelectDayControl selectDayControl) {
    this.selectDayControl = selectDayControl;
    ...
}
```

Now I want to add both to the FXML file by referencing the `@NamedArgs` field with the `fx:id` of the other component.

```
<SelectDayControl fx:id="daySelect"/>
<SelectWeekControl dayControl="${daySelect}" fx:id="weekSelect"/>
```

Unfortunately the second line fails with the following error message:

> Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Cannot bind to untyped object.

The only [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36293582/javafx-binding-fails-with-cannot-bind-to-untyped-object) referring to the same issue has an unsatisfying answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why the code you tried doesn't work, but the following version seems to work ok:

```xml
<SelectWeekControl fx:id="selectWeekControl">
    <selectDayControl>
        <SelectDayControl fx:id="selectDayControl" />
    </selectDayControl>
</SelectWeekControl>
```

and (if you need the `SelectDayControl` defined elsewhere in the FXML file) so does

```xml
<SelectDayControl fx:id="selectDayControl" />

<SelectWeekControl fx:id="selectWeekControl">
    <selectDayControl>
        <fx:reference source="selectDayControl" />
    </selectDayControl>
</SelectWeekControl>
```

Comment: Cool, thank you, it works! But I would like to add some more information for other people with the same issue: `SelectDayControl` has to be defined *before* `SelectWeekControl` and although the second approach is valid, IntelliJ highlights it in red and says "cannot resolve symbol"